# Reuse Access Token Throughout ASP.NET Core App (via DI)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, microsoft-dynamics, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a ASP.NET Core app that I'm using OIDC (Microsoft Azure AD) to authenticate users to my app.  I have added a ton of APIs to the Registered Application in Azure AD including Dynamics.  How can I access the access token in my middleware?  I created a class for the sole purpose of communicating with Dynamics and would like to reuse the access token generated during authentication to my app.  How and where do I get it from?  I have tried all the usual suspects such as the following:

```
var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString(); // null
```

and

```
var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result; // null
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are multiple ways one can integrate AAD AuthN in their apps. If you can specifiy which approach (doc, sample) you used, a better answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

To get access token for calling Dynamics API with the authenticated user context, application should get access token using OBO flow. MSAL.NET has method to do so.

```
string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
```

You can refer this [ASP.NET Core Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/3.-Web-api-call-Microsoft-graph-for-personal-accounts) and has the similar scenario that you are trying to achive.